# To force key type in interface

Tags: typescript

I have a problem in TypeScript, when I want to force type on key of interface. I have an interface that contains callback and other types. I want to check if the key type in the interface is callback. If not, I want that compiling identify it and raise error about the type.

Example:

```
class Emitter<O,
    OK extends keyof O,
    OV extends O[OK] & {(data:D):void},
    D> {

    constructor(public options: O,
        public name: OK) { }

    emit(data: D) {
         this.options[this.name] &&
                this.options[this.name](data); 
    }
}

let options: {
    onSave: (data: string) => void,
    size: number
};

let myEmitter1 = new Emitter(options, "onSave");
// I need error next line about "size" type.
let myEmitter2 = new Emitter(options, "size");
```

Comment: Hey again! You'll need to relax your constraints if you want to make it work. For example, can you just separate the `options` object into two different objects, one for the callbacks and one for the others?

Comment: It's not the my question, I don't want to make two different types.

Comment: I understand that you prefer not to, but it doesn't seem like there's a solution to your problem unless you're willing to relax your constraints.